# .htaccess url rewrite - remove .php - add trailing slash - and shorten query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been working on a CMS recently, and wanted to remove the .php add a trailing slash and remove query strings e.g. page.php?page=contact to page/contact

So far my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# This is a .htaccess file
# Don't edit it.

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php\?page=([^&\s]+)&?
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

other then that, I can't figure out how to shorten the query string. I've looked around on and couldn't find any other questions specific to this...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood you. I though you just needed to truncate the query string. This would pull the `page` parameter value from the query string and append it to the URL. `?` truncates query string as before.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php\?page=([^&\s]+)&?
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I added in: RewriteRule ^page/$ page.php - for that it loads the page.php as page/. Thanks for all your help. I selected your reply as the answer, but is it possible to remove ?page= and just keep the url as page/home ?

Comment: What's the URL you're using in the browser? `/page.php?page=home` ?? and at which place have you added your rule? Ordering is important.

Comment: I am using /page.php?page=home - i wanted to make the url /page/home ... so the url would be shorter and easier to understand/remember. so far with your help I have been able to remove the .php so the url looks like /page/?page=home

Comment: Does your htaccess look exactly like my answer? That should have taken care of it. If not can you update the question or open a new one with your current htaccess code.

Comment: This is what my .htaccess file looks like now.

# This is a .htaccess file
# Don't edit it.
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php\?page=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/%1/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?page=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^page/$ page.php

I updated my topic.

Comment: What happens when you remove the last rule?

Comment: 404 not found - the page you requested cannot be found. and it adds in HTML/1.1/ ??

Comment: And the browser url? Did it change from `/page.php?page=home` or stayed the same?

Comment: /page.php?page=home changed to /page/home%20HTML/1.1

Comment: Change `page=([^&]+)` to `page=([^&\s]+)` and you're set.

Comment: Didn't work, still get the same problems. Am i allowed to share the link to the page for that you can see the problem?

Comment: If it still appended HTTP/1.1 you need to clear browser cache.

Comment: It now works! ve3rhe.ca/page.php?page=home - thanks for working with me on this problem.

Comment: Since, it works now; would appreciate if you restore my upvote as well.